# Non-zero measured single point sets under sigma-finitely additive measure are countable

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Problem:

> If $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ is a measure space,  $\mu$ is $\sigma-$finitely additive(exists an increase set list$\left\{X_i\right\}$ such that $\cup_{i=1}^\infty X_i=X$and$\mu(X_i)<\infty$), prove that $D_\mu=\left\{x\in X:\mu(\left\{x\right\}>0\right\}$ is countable.

In fact I just have a little idea about the question. I want to use the '$\sigma-$finitely additive' to say $D_\mu$ is countable(Construct an increase set list). But it seems impossible because we don't know whether$D_\mu$ is countable.

Comment: What is your definition of a measure space. In particular, do you require that $X$ has finite measure? I assume so. Then find some $n$ and uncountably many singletons such that the measure of each of them is at least $\frac1n$. Get a contradiction, obtaining that the measure of $X$ is infinite (bigger than any number given in advance).

Comment: For the first one, the counting measure on $\mathbb{R}$ is a counter example.

Comment: To clarify my hint, assume that $D_\mu$ were uncountable, and let $D_\mu(n)=\{x\in X:\mu(\left\{x\right\}>\frac1n\}$. Show that there is $n$ such that $D_\mu(n)$ is uncountable. Get a contradiction, as suggested in the previous comment. This should answer your first question. It is recommended at this website, I believe, that you don't ask multiple questions within the same post, but rather post the second question separately (given it does not seem that closely related to the first...what is the motivation behind these not very closely related questions ... I hope not just your homework?)

Comment: @UmeshShankar counting measure does not provide for a measure space, if you require (as you should, in the definition of a measure space) that $X$ is measurable, that is, that $X$ has a finite measure. Well, if it is not required, then your counterexample works.

Comment: I'm confused. Isn't the whole set always in the sigma algebra? The Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$ with the Lebesgue sigma algebra, not a measure space now?

Comment: @UmeshShankar I am confused too, and different books may have different definitions. In particular, I *suspect* that if the measure is only required to be finitely- (rather than countably-) additive, then perhaps $\mathcal A$ is only required to be an algebra (closed under finite, but not necessarily countable unions and intersections (and closed under complements)) but not necessarily a $\sigma$-algebra, and that in addition $m(X)$ is finite. I asked the OP for a clarification, and in the absence of that I tend to assume that $m(X)$ is finite, but I don't really know.

Comment: @Mirko Sorry I forget the sigma-finitely additive in the tittle. In fact this problem is a step in my proof of a problem about multiple measure. But my teacher point that my proof of this    step(this problem) is wrong. When I try to find some ideas to solve it, I find the original second question which is delete now. Because I think it's interesting. Please forgive me.qwq

Comment: @UmeshShankar, actually Vstal: You could certainly post the other question separately if you could explain why you find it interesting. Re this question, I think I start to see what you mean. My hint remains valid, with a little addition. So you mean $\sigma$-additive (not $\sigma$-finitely additive, which I don't think is established terminology). So, if $D$ were uncountable, then first find $m$ such that $D\cap X_m$ is uncountable, then try to follow my previous hints. If you can't follow (given my hints get a bit disconnected) I could write the entire answer ... I think, if correct

Comment: After the latest edit, I think that you want to say that $\mu$ is ‘$\sigma$-finite’, not ‘$\sigma$-finitely additive’. The latter is not a standard term, while the former means what you said in your explanation. Then the question makes sense.

Comment: @TobyBartels I think you are right ... I noticed the confusing terminology, and I suggested $\sigma$-additive, but I think that indeed $\sigma$-finite is the correct term. I think my hints above could be put together to form a complete answer, but I will wait for now.

Comment: @Mikro Thank you! I understand what you mean. From $D_\mu$ to $D_\mu(n)$ is something I didn't know before to deal with the 'coutable'.

Comment: @Vstal You are welcome... you may try to post an answer to your own question, if you understand it better now. (Since the latter seems to be the case, I won't post an answer for now, unless something else needs to be clarified.)